# Generics in a bidirectional association

Tags: generics, inheritance, scala, bidirectional

Let's say I have two classes A and B, with B a subtype of A. This is only part of a richer type hierarchy, obviously, but I don't think that's relevant. Assume A is the root of the hierarchy. There is a collection class C that keeps track of a list of A's. However, I want to make C generic, so that it is possible to make an instance that only keeps B's and won't accept A's.

```
class A(val c: C[A]) {
    c.addEntry(this)
}
class B(c: C[A]) extends A(c)
class C[T <: A]{
    val entries = new ArrayBuffer[T]()
    def addEntry(e: T) { entries += e }
}
object Generic {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val c = new C[B]()
        new B(c)
    }
}
```

The code above obviously give the error 'type mismatch: found C[B], required C[A]' on the `new B(c)` line.

I'm not sure how this can be fixed. It's not possible to make C covariant in T (like `C[+T <: A]`) because the ArrayBuffer is non-variantly typed in T. It's not possible to make the constructor of B require a C[B] because C can't be covariant.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? I'm a complete Scala newbie, so any ideas and tips might be helpful. Thank you!

EDIT:
Basically, what I'd like to have is that the compiler accepts both

```
val c = new C[B]()
new B(c)
```

and

```
val c = new C[A]()
new B(c)
```

but would reject

```
val c = new C[B]()
new A(c)
```

It's probably possible to relax the typing of the ArrayBuffer in C to be A instead of T, and thus in the addEntry method as well, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not possible to make C covariant in T (like `C[+T <: A]`) because the ArrayBuffer is non-variantly typed in T

Not only because of this. The type of `addEntry` is enough to disallow it:

```
val a: A = ...
val b: B = ...

val cb: C[B] = ...

cb.addEntry(b) // works
cb.addEntry(a) // doesn't and shouldn't
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but seems to work:

```
class A(val c: C[A]) {
  c.addEntry(this.asInstanceOf[c.X])
}

class B(c: C[B]) extends A(c)

class C[+T <: A] {
    type X <: T
    val entries = new ArrayBuffer[X]()
    def addEntry(e: X) { entries += e }
}

object Generic {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val c = new C(){ type T = B }
        new B(c)
    }
}
```

Of course I would be interested in a proper solution as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the instances of A, you have to pass an instance of C[A] to the constructor of B since every B is also an A:

```
def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val c = new C[A]()
    new B(c)
}
```

If however you want to keep track of the Bs then you can't delegate this down to A since A doesn't know anything about B.

Overall, I have the feeling your problem is somewhat ill posed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it was possible. Then you'd be able to do this:

```
class A(val c: C[A]) {
    c.addEntry(this)
}
class B(c: C[A]) extends A(c)
class C[+T <: A]{
    val entries: ArrayBuffer[T] @uncheckedVariance = new ArrayBuffer[T]()
    def addEntry(e: T @uncheckedVariance) { entries += e }
}
object Generic {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        // Everything's fine so far...
        val c = new C[B]()
        c.addEntry(new B(c))
        // but, suddenly...
        val ca: C[A] = c
        ca.addEntry(new A(ca))
        // a problem appears!
        c.entries forall {
            case thing: B => true // ok
            case otherThing => false // not ok -- c now contains an A!
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to run this code will result in a class cast exception.

**Edit**

You added this requirement:

> ```
> val c = new C[B]()
> new B(c)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> val c = new C[A]()
> new B(c)
> ```
>
> but would reject
>
> ```
> val c = new C[B]()
> new A(c)
> ```

However, if `B` is initialized with `C[B]`, and given that `B` extends `A`, then *`B`* will initialize `A` with `C[B]`, thereby violating the last requirement.

Comment: It indeed goes wrong for exactly the reasons you describe here if C is covariant, but that's not strictly a requirement. I don't think there's any need to make C[B] a subtype of C[A].

Comment: @Verhoevenv If `C[B]` was not a subtype of `C[A]`, then how do you expect to `new B(c)` to work, if `c` of type `C[B]`? I'm looking at your revision right now, and you are asking for something impossible.